# Accuracy of angular difference: direct difference or difference identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Can anyone point out if there is a difference in the accuracy of the result of calculating an angle difference when using the difference between two arctan values or when using the difference formula i.e.

Method 1 (direct difference):

\begin{equation}
\delta\alpha = \alpha_2 - \alpha_1 = \arctan(f2) - \arctan(f1)
\end{equation}

**Or**

Method 2 (difference identity):

\begin{equation}
\delta\alpha = \arctan\left(\frac{f_2 - f_1}{1+f_1f_2}\right)
\end{equation}

Where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are fractions of two numbers.

Are there reasons to favor one method over the other?

Answer (score 1):

For small not too close $f_1, f_2$ the formulas make no difference since $\arctan x \approx x$ so there's no loss of precision.

But consider case when both $f_1, f_2 \gg 1$. Then each $\arctan$ is close to $\pi / 2$ and there will be a significant error when subtracting two close values.

Consider $f_{1,2} = 10^6 \pm 1$. The second method gives
$$
\delta \alpha = \arctan \frac{2}{1 + 10^{12} - 1} \approx
2 \cdot 10^{-12}.
$$
This result can be reliably computed even with single precision.
To obtain the same result using the first formula you have to compute $\arctan (10^6 \pm 1)$ with twelve digits (!) since both differ from $\pi/2$ only by a value of $10^{-12}$ magnitude.